# how to put | between content lines of a text file?

Tags: sed

I have a file containing:

```
L1
L2
L3
.
.
.
L512
```

I want to change its content to :

```
L1 | L2 | L3 | ... | L512
```

It seems so easy , but its now 1 hour Im sitting and trying to make it, I tried to do it by sed, but didn't get what I want. It seems that sed just inserts empty lines between the content, any suggestion please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed: How can I replace a newline (\n)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n)

Comment: I tried as suggested in that post,  sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/|/g' labellist,  but it seems not to work, I also tried to put \ before | , but no work

Comment: and using -i option: sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/|/g' labellist, I get this error: 
sed: 1: "labellist": extra characters at the end of l command

Comment: `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ | /g' file` works for me..

Comment: @KianStar, what's your OS and version of sed?

Comment: What's the objection to `paste -sd'|' yourfile`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Probably, lack of information

Comment: @MarkSetchell Paste does not work for me: `paste -sd' | ' file` gives strange spaceing. With six line I get: `L1 L2|L3 L4 L5|L6`

Comment: sorry for being late, I'm working on mac OS X , maybe its why its not working properly with me?

Comment: @Jotne, the delimiter in `paste -d` should be 1 character, otherwise it is treated as a *set* of characters, and each char is used in turn.

Comment: @KianStar Some strange that you did accept a solution that did not work (fixed now) when there was other good working solution.

Comment: Jotne I accepted it because the awk option suggested by hek2mgl worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed this requires to read the whole input into a buffer and afterwards replace all newlines by `|`, like this:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ | /g' input.txt
```

Part 1 - buffering input

`:a`       defines a label called 'a'
`N`        gets the next line from input and appends it to the pattern buffer
`$!ba`       jumps to `a` unless the end of input is reached

Part 2 - replacing newlines by `|`

`s/\n/|/`  execute the substitute command on the pattern buffern

---

As you can see, this is very inefficient since it requires to:

- read the complete input into memory
- operate three times on the input: 1. reading, 2. substituting, 3. printing

Therefore I would suggest to use awk which can do it in one loop:

```
awk 'NR==1{printf $0;next}{printf " | "$0}END{print ""}' input.txt
```

Comment: To get newline at end put `END {print ""}` to the `awk`

Comment: For some reason `sed` only works for me with first two lines.  Rest are ignored.

Comment: Which version of sed are you using?

Comment: @Jotne My fault! I missed the `/g` option. Now it works as expected, I have also tried with `sed --posix` to  get sure it works with all posix compatible versions of `sed`.

Comment: Works ok now.  This is why I always post output of my command in the solution (if its not to long)

Comment: Yeah, this mostly makes sense. Thanks for pointing out the error for me in this case!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one `sed`

```
sed ':a;N;s/\n/ | /g;ta' file
L1 | L2 | L3 | ... | L512
```

And one `awk`

```
awk '{printf("%s%s",sep,$0);sep=" | "} END {print ""}' file
L1 | L2 | L3 | ... | L512
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 's/\n/ |/g unless(eof)' file
```

Comment: You should add a space after `|` to get it correct :)

Answer (score 0):

if space between `|` is not mandatory

```
tr "\n" '|' YourFile
```

Comment: This is just the same as Wintermute posted and gives an extra `|` at end of line, and does not give space around `|`

Comment: sorry didn't see Wintermute answer (and still not). Good point for the last `|` so it need at least a pipe sequence wioth a sed or similar.

Comment: Wintermute did delete his anwer since it did not give correct output.  If you have more than 10000 points you can see the deleted answer.

Answer (score -1):

Several options, including those mentioned here:

```
paste -sd'|' file
sed ':a;N;s/\n/ | /g;ta' file
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ | /g' file
perl -0pe 's/\n/ | /g;s/ \| $/\n/' file
perl -0nE 'say join " | ", split /\n/' file
perl -E 'chomp(@x=<>); say join " | ", @x' file
mapfile -t ary < file; (IFS="|"; echo "${ary[*]}")
awk '{printf("%s%s",sep,$0);sep=" | "} END {print ""}' file
```

Comment: `past` does not work with `<space>|<space>`. This is just a collection of others post here :(  (except perl and map)